# How to disable django forms radio button depending on anotehr radio button value

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form with two sets of radio buttons. I would like to block two choices in the second set depending on the selected button in the first set.

How can I do that? Do I have to write a function for it in views?

forms.py

```
DOWNLOAD_CHOICES = [("all", "All values"), 
("all_divide", "All values separated per IfcType"),
("unique", "Unique values"), 
("unique_divide", "Unique values separated per IfcType")]


FORMAT_CHOICES = [("xlsx", "Excel (.xlsx)"),
    ("csv", "comma-separated values (.csv)")]

class DownloadForm(forms.Form):
    file_format = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FORMAT_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    file_download = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DOWNLOAD_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

model_form_download.html

```
<form action="" name="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
 </form>
```

I think that my views.py is not relevant to this question, so I am not posting it now. It is too long anyways...

Comment: Please be clearer about what you want to achieve. What do you mean with "block" choices?

Comment: You don't have to write any Python code, but you need to write some JS code.

Comment: @yagus sorry I may have used the wrong terminology. Let me try again. So the first sets of radio buttons has two buttons, "A" and "B". The seconds set has four buttons: 1,2,3 and 4. If the user selects "B" only buttons 1 and 2 should be available for selection. Buttons 3 and 4 should be disabled, or not available...

Comment: @bichanna I did a tutorial where one uses JS for this purpose. But there the radio buttons were defined with HTML. Here they are defined in Django Forms so I have no idea how to influence specific radion buttons if they are defined in HTML only as "{{ form.as_p }}"

Comment: Radio buttons are always rendered as HTML. To see the rendered HTML just open the dev tools of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript. For example, using jQuery:

```
function setOptions() {
    if ($("input[name=file_download][value=unique]").prop('checked')) {
      $("input[name=file_format][value=csv]").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("input[name=file_format][value=csv]").prop('disabled', false);
};

$('input[name="file_download"]').change(function () {
    setOptions();
};

setOptions();
```